# Create a Spring Bean programmatically, but with Autowired within it

Tags: spring, prototype, javabeans, factory, autowired

How do I instantiate a Spring Bean that has some `@Autowired` beans within it?  The caveat is that the instance bean type must be discovered dynamically at runtime (whereas the `@Autowired` bean can still be singleton).

Example:

**Interface**

```
public interface Client {
  public void process(String s);
}
```

**ClientA.class**

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ClientA implements Client {
  @Autowired
  MyHelperService svc;

  public void process(String s) {...}
}
```

**ClientB.class**

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ClientB implements Client {
  @Autowired
  MyHelperService svc;

  public void process(String s) {...}
}
```

**ClientFactory.class**

```
@Component
public class ClientFactory {
  public Client createClient(String type) {
    .. create an instance of ClientA or ClientB ..
  }
}
```

**MyService.class**

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  ClientFactory factory;

  Client client;

  public void processList(List<String> requests) {
    for(String s: requests) {
      client = factory.createClient(s);
      client.process(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Though this sample code is for illustration purposes here, the pattern applies to our needs.  More specifically, we are multi-threading our app by creating `Callable<?>` tasks and submitting them to an `ExecutorService` with parallel threads (and it's those tasks which each need their own instance of `Client` whose lifespan should end after we call it's `process` method).

The client instances use a singleton shared `MyHelperService` service.  Since that should be `@Autowired`, our factory can't simply construct the clients like `new ClientA()` or `new ClientB()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should know that adding a @Bean annotation on method, does not create a bean it just creates a bean definition, and only after calling this method spring will create a bean for you.

You can use `applicationContext` to get bean defined with `prototype` scope wherever you want in your application and your `ClientFactory` is a good place to do that

```
public class ClientFactory {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ClientFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public Client createInstance(String request) {
        if (request.equals("A")) {
            return applicationContext.getBean("clientA", Client.class);
        }
        return applicationContext.getBean("clientB", Client.class);
    }
}
```

And your bean configuration will look like this

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Client clientA(){
        return new ClientA();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Client clientB(){
        return new ClientB();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientFactory clientFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        return new ClientFactory(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

Then you just need to inject your `ClientFactory` and create instances of the `Client` beans with `clientFactory.createInstance("A");`

Comment: @syzmon_prz  When I call `applicationContext.getBean(Client.class, "A")` I get `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` stating that expected a single match but found `clientA` and `clientB`.   Also, the debug breakpoint I set in `ClientFactory.createInstance` is never hit.  How do I confirm my `@Configuration` was loaded and how does Spring know to call that `createInstance` method?

Comment: @syzmon_prz Nevermind.  I made sure to give my `@Bean` a name and then to use that same name in the `applicationContext.getBean` method.  So Spring is marrying them up now and I'm successfully getting my instance beans.  Thank you!

Comment: Don't. Do it the other way around. So you do't have to work with the context in your application. Make the factory and the beans Spring managed and move the call to `getBean` to your factory. That way you don't need the getbean call in other methods and your own code can be clean. The factory can be a singleton that way.

Comment: @M.Deinum really nice! Will edit my answer with your method